# How to calculate the temperature of an exoplanet?

Tags: exoplanet

I was given an exoplanet similar in size and distance to host star to our own earth. It's orbiting a star with luminosity six times our sun, the greenhouse coefficient 0.3, bond albedo 0.3.

I would like to calculate the approximate surface temperature (i.e. close enough to know whether it is in habitable range).

**Disclaimer:** This question was on a past exam and we never got our test back.

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature The answer and necessary formula is given there. Actually, I just realised (and reversed my downvote of your question), that this does not incorporate your greenhouse effect.Can you define what you mean by "greenhouse coefficient"?

Comment: I think greenhouse factor reduces outgoing radiation from stuff like vapor in the air. The Earth's greenhouse coefficient is about 0.4 I think. I plugged the numbers into an open simulator and got a habitable range (it did not take into account 6x luminosity) and after plugging it into the equation it gives me a large amount of Kelvin. There are many variants of the equation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know what the greenhouse effect is, I want to know how your greenhouse coefficient is *defined*.

Comment: [Related question](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10113/how-to-calculate-the-expected-surface-temperature-of-a-planet/10116#10116).

Comment: This should help, it utilizes the greenhouse coefficient http://phl.upr.edu/library/notes/surfacetemperatureofplanets

Comment: Here's an easy to use calculator, you will need to decide upon a greenhouse coefficient and enter one, it won't calculate the amount of greenhouse coefficient for you; only the result of the variables that you enter: http://www.astro.indiana.edu/ala/PlanetTemp/index.html -- A website that might give you a ballpark value to try is here: http://terraforming.wikia.com/wiki/Greenhouse_Calculator -- A tutorial on greenhouse effect is here: https://www.lpl.arizona.edu/~showman/greenhouse.html

Comment: See this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/be3hqx/how_is_the_temperature_of_exoplanets_determined/) and [this paper](https://digitalcommons.conncoll.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=physicshp)